# Setting filename property for TOpenFileDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When I set the Filename property of a TFileOpenDialog and then execute it I see just the final 14 characters of the filename selected in the Filename field.  If I press <kbd>Home</kbd> I can see that the entire string is there, but I'd like it to display properly of course.  I've tested on two Windows 7 and one Windows 8 machine with the same results.  Does anyone have any suggestions or hints on how to solve the issue?

```
FileOpenDialog1.FileName :=
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\available_downloads_en.htm';
if FileOpenDialog1.Execute then
  ShowMessage(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);
```

Initial display showing problem:
[image: Image showing problem]

The entire string after pressing Home:
[image: How I think it should look]

Comment: This is a bug of the IFileDialog, it seems was introduced in Windows 7, read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/c0c79498-3399-4346-b514-b15336cd7c68/

Comment: Yeah, this is well-known.

Comment: Does anyone know if this problem still exists in Windows 10? (It seems so to me.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TFileOpenDialog` is just a thin wrapper around Microsoft's `IFileDialog` interface on Windows Vista and later.  You don't have control over how the dialog itself behaves when it is shown.  If it only shows the last characters (and I was able to reproduce that behavior on my Win7 box), than that is simply how the dialog works in general.  However, with that said, `IFileDialog` does allow the absolute folder path and just the filename to be set separately, and that is how they should be used, but `TFileOpenDialog` does not make or expose that separation, unfortunately (Embarcadero bug?).  So if you need that functionality, you will have to use `IFileDialog` directly and not use `TFileOpenDialog` at all.

Comment: You can get the `IFileDialog` from `TFileOpenDialog`. No need to abandon it completely.

Comment: What's the second part of the answer about? Surely the Delphi wrapper presents the full path to the file, but when you set that it results in a change to folder and a change to file. I can't see how this addresses the question. A simple, "this is a known problem with no workaround" would suffce.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `TFileOpenDialog` does not create its `IFileDialog` instance until `Execute()` is called, at which point it is too late to change how the `TFileOpenDialog` properties get assigned to it, unless you derive from `TFileOpenDialog` and override `Execute()` with your own implementation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the entire `FileName` property value is passed as-is to the `IFileDialog.SetFileName()` method, which displays the entire string as-is in the dialog's edit box. What I was getting at is `TFileOpenDialog` does not separate the folder path from the file name so it can call `IFileDialog.SetFolder('C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\')` and `IFileDialog.SetFileName('available_downloads_en.htm')` individually. That might have addressed the problem if it did that.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification. FWIW, I use `IFileDialog` directly!!

Comment: I modified Vcl.Dialogs to perform the setfolder and setfilename separately, but note that it does not resolve the problem (I may have misunderstood the comments suggesting this.)  It looks like David's "this is a known problem with no workaround" is the most accurate assessment.